# CameraPreview does not take all the place

Tags: flutter

In a Flutter application, I am using the [camera Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) .

It works correctly but the `CameraPreview` does not take all the available size. Here the widgets tree and the result:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: //AppBar(),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
        ),
      ),
      _buildQRCodeOverlay(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

According to several threads on StackOverflow, I can apply a `Transformation` in order to have a "fullscreen" preview:

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;

return Scaffold(
  appBar: buildAppBar(title),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: cameraController.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      _buildQRCodeOverlay(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

But In my case, It does not work :

[image]

How can I remove the white borders I have and keep the aspect ratio?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I finally found the issue. The examples of a fullscreen preview camera only works when the `ResolutionPreset` is set to `medium`. It does not work when it is set to `high` which is was my case.

According to the documentation, the `CameraController.value.previewSize` is not the same when the `ResolutionPreset` is `medium` (720x480) and `high` (1280x720). So, the `CameraController.value.aspectRatio` cannot be the same.

Also note that (at least on my phone), the 1280 is the width and 720 the height. It means that the orientation is not the same as the phone.

So in my case, I have created a function that returns the aspect ratio of the `CameraController` in which on I always divide the "big" value by the smaller one:

```dart
  double _getCameraRatio()
  {
    final height = _cameraController.value.previewSize.height;
    final width = _cameraController.value.previewSize.width;

    if (width > 0.0 && height >= width)
    {
      return height / width;
    }

    if (height > 0.0 && width >= height)
    {
      return width / height;
    }

    return 1.0;
  }
```

Then, I do a similar thing in order to have the `Scaffold` (minus the `AppBar`) aspect ratio:

```dart
final scaffoldAspectRatio = _getScaffoldBodyAspectRatio(MediaQuery.of(context).size, Scaffold.of(context).appBarMaxHeight);
```

```dart
double _getScaffoldBodyAspectRatio(Size size, double appBarMaxHeight)
{
  return ((size.height - appBarMaxHeight) / size.width);
}
```

Finally, I can calculate the scale to apply:

```dart
Transform.scale(
  scale: _getCameraPreviewScale(aspectRatio, scaffoldAspectRatio),
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
    child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
  ),
),
```

```dart
_getCameraPreviewScale(double cameraAspectRatio, double scaffoldAspectRatio)
  {
    if (cameraAspectRatio >= scaffoldAspectRatio)
    {
      return cameraAspectRatio / scaffoldAspectRatio;
    }

    if (scaffoldAspectRatio > cameraAspectRatio)
    {
      return scaffoldAspectRatio / cameraAspectRatio;
    }
  }
```

It seems to work correctly with at least `ResolutionPreset.medium` and `ResolutionPreset.high`.